# How to use ? in URL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out a way to have one PHP page to display all of my blog post but have the URL decide what post is requested from that database. Something kind of like this: `localhost/bolg/posts.php?pid=1` In my database I have it set up to where each post has an ID associated with it. So what I want is something that put the pid=1 and put it in the MySQL code. Here is the PHP code of the post.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, title, content, date FROM posts where id =3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h1> ". $row["title"]. "</h1>". $row["content"]. "" . $row["date"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: so finally what you want?

Comment: I want to be able to have a single php page but have code in the url like localhost/blog/post.php?pid=1 and grab the blog post with the id 1 from the database.

and have pid=2 grab the post with the id of 2

Comment: @RiggsFolly what sir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you enter `example.com?pid=10` in the browser address bar, you can capture that variable `pid` using the `$_GET` ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)) array which PHP automatically fills for you when a page is called with a querystring.

Using your existing code as a start point you can

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, content, date FROM posts where id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['pid']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        // while looop is not necessary, you are only returning one row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "<h1> ". $row["title"]. "</h1>". $row["content"]. "" . $row["date"] . "<br>";
    }
    $conn->close();
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

**Notice** I took the liberty of amending your database access code to use prepared and parameterised query and binding the values to avoid [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). ***You should always use this technique in the future***

Comment: Of course good point about paratremized query, however, shouldn't be `$_GET['pid']` bound as INT?

Comment: $conn is undefined if $_GET['pid'] not set, just saying

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Very good point. I never bother so forget to sanity check that bit :)

Comment: @biesior So I always thought, but apparently, and I tested it, it couldn't give a jot what you use :) But I will fix it anyway, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the fix, actually both will work, however using integer is probably a little bit safer.

Comment: Actually, I have one more question, for which I cannot find a simple answer, Fore years before querying SQL with incoming data we were always intval for numeric values, now, with paratremised queries it's skipped, can you explain why is that? Normally even if used with string type I'd would use it as `$stmt->bind_param('s', intval($_GET['pid']));`

Comment: @biesior Not sure, maybe from the `mysql_` extension days

Comment: I tried the anser and get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in D:\xampp2\htdocs\DEV\blog\posts\test.php on line 8

Comment: @Ex0byte There were syntax errors in this piece of code. I fixed it for RiggsFolly